# Fix for background-attachment bug in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, parallax

When viewing this site http://jsfiddle.net/dN4S4/1405/ on chrome with a Mac retina display the background is not correctly rendered. This is the CSS used:

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#cards{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.card-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(url here);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.card{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.875);
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I found out that this is a known issue but have not found a fix that actually works. It renders as expected on any other browser and even works fine in chrome when viewing the site with a "normal" display.

For simplicity I am using the same image in the demo, however I want to use different images creating the "parallax" effect.

Please not that "position: absolute" on the body does not cause this issue. It also occurs with different "position" and "display" values.

Any suggestions on how to make it render correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked and tweaked your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s34bhvza/3/) to get the parallax effect to work pretty much that way that I would expect it to work, but you'll have to check it out for yourself to verify.

The main insight here is that the `background-attachment: fixed` should be applied to the parent/container `div` that will not "scroll". Think of your `card-wrapper` class being a very, very tall container, holding all the individual `card`s that scroll upwards, and all of this while the `fixed` container, which has the background image, remains fixed in the background.